# Statistics Inverse Method in Rstudio

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, math-software

I have a problem.

I have to generate 10.000 random variables using the inverse method for Logistic distribution and Cauchy distribution.

I know their corresponding probability density functions and distribution functions, and I think I have to calculate with hand on paper the inverse of F(x) for each one, right?
 But I have no idea how to write it in Rstudio.

Please, help me!

Comment: First question: yes, you actually need $F^{-1}(U)$, where $U \sim \operatorname{Unif}(0,1)$.  Last sentence: can you search for similar code?

Comment: I've tried. I saw something similar but what I don't understand it's where I have to use the distribution name besides for the inverse . I mean when I use dname, rname... I write runif or rlogistic ?

Comment: Inverse cumulative for logistics is the logit pdf function... Also IIRC its all implemented in R as the quantile function for that distribution.  Google it up, or check help for any of the distributions, you should also get associated q-function.

Comment: by the way, "RStudio" is a particular interface/development environment for R.  R is the programming language - this question isn't at all RStudio-specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about the context (e.g. is this homework?) For most common probability distributions, R has built-in functions for

- CDF (`p***`, e.g. `pnorm()`
- probability distribution/density function (`d***`, e.g. `dnorm()`)
- inverse CDF/quantile function (`q***`, e.g. `qnorm()`)
- random deviate generator (`r***`, e.g. `rnorm()`)

You do have to know that the suffixes for Cauchy and logistic are `cauchy` and `logis`. If you ever need an exhaustive list of probability distribution implementations in R, you can see the [probability distributions task view](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Distributions.html) ...

The random deviate generators usually have good/special purpose algorithms, which are often better (more efficient) than the inverse method. So the most *efficient* way to generate random deviates for the logistic and Cauchy distributions would be to use the `rlogis()` and `rcauchy()` functions, respectively. But if you insist on using the inverse method, `qlogis(runif(10000),...)` or `qcauchy(runif(10000),...)` would do what you want (`...` would be optional parameter values: looking at `?qlogis`, `?qcauchy`, both distributions use location parameter 0 and scale parameter  1 by default).

Comment: It's for a project, I have to use specific methods. Thank you so much, it's much clear now.